# MVC cshtml file require rename in ordered to get breakpoint to hit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hey stackoverflow,

I have a MVC project that contains cshtml files.  After getting a latest from sourcesafe, I can no longer set break points on a cshtml file that was modified. I tried to clean and rebuild and checked all settings from web.config file to debugging properties. I get the famous no symbol is loaded error.

But the funny thing is if I rename the file then the break point will hit (I have to rename  return PartialView function as well). But once I do that, then the break point will hit.

As soon as I rename the file back, then the break point will not hit again. So I know it's not the configuation settings. But I cannot rename the file because the team is using it so I have to get my system to be able to set break point on with the original file name.

Can someone tell me the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Try cleaning the temp ASP.NET files folder : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137457/asp-net-temporary-files-cleanup   Sometimes old files linger in there and can end up being served in your app, even though you have newer versions available. It's worth cleaning that folder anyway, since it can get very big.

Comment: Yea I did that, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: I figure out the issue. I had 2 files of the same name but in different directories. One version was used but not in the solution, another was not used but was in the solution so I can't break into it.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out. I bet you're relieved? :)

Comment: Yes, but the compiler really need to catch this and not just let me guess.