# VS2019 : adding or renaming file in asp.net core project terribly slow

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

When we add a file, create a folder, rename a file or folder it lasts for seconds until this is done.

Even when directly doing those changes on the folder structure, it takes seconds in VS2019 to see them.

In other projects, part of the same solution we do not have this problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not attach a debugger (VS itself will be sufficient) to VS and see what is happening in these slow periods? Alternatively/additionally, attach a Performance Profiler like e.g. [this one](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) to VS.

Comment: VS cannot attach to itself.

Comment: I'm doing this since years. Of course you need to start a second instance of VS.

Answer (score 3):

> STEP 1 Clear  Cache

1. Win+E to open File Explorer
   [image]
2. Click tab "File" and "Change folder and search options"
   [image]
3. Click Clear

> STEP 2 Minimize Index scope

I. Open Windows Settings and Select "Indexing Options"

[image]

II. Click "Modify"

[image]

III. Unselect Driver C:// and others

[image]

Comment: We already applied this in the past. Not a solution.

Comment: Sorry for not solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do the `dotnet restore` in a command prompt in the web application directory. This solved the long freezes.
2. Clean this directory:

%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Temporary ASP.NET Files

3. You can exclude extra folders by adding the  property to the .csproj file, like `<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);ClientLib\node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>`

references here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/35570/create-new-file-and-file-rename-are-extremely-slow.html?page=1&pageSize=10&sort=votes&type=problem

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms366723(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#compilation-folder-location

[ASP.NET Temporary files cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137457/asp-net-temporary-files-cleanup)

Comment: The slowness happens as you have donwnloaded the sources. No caching / temp files involved I guess.

Comment: Is an asp.net core mvc project so no client folders for angular or alike.

Comment: What about other solutions on my post, like dotnet restore, do you try that?

Comment: Was not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had slow file add, delete, save, and slow folder add.

I just fixed mine, however my project also has React frontend, the culprit was the "node_modules" folder. I had moved the project from another drive and VS2019 included it as an active folder. Excluding it from the project brought everything back to normal. Since my project is .Net Core 3.1 + React - doing this might serve others - not sure if the OP is using node.js

In Solutions Explore --> Right click node_modules folder --> select "Exclude from Project"

If you are using source control (git) will still work ok as will the rest of your application.